# VS2015 ASP.NET 5 Empty project doesn't work, can't find ConfigurationBuilder.Build

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dnx

Trying out the new VS2015 projects. I was following [this tutorial](http://proudmonkey.azurewebsites.net/asp-net-5-getting-started-with-mvc-6/) but it's missing something. When I run it I get a 500 error:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.IConfiguration Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()'.
at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.RuntimeHttpApplication.ApplicationStart(IHttpApplication application)
at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.HttpApplicationBase.InvokeApplicationStart(IHttpApplication application)

.NET Framework version 4.0.30319.42000   |   Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS version 1.0.0-beta5-11951   |   IIS version 10.0.10117.0 (fbl_srv2_iis_dev(sujitn).150512-1839)   |   Need help?
```

After some reading I discovered that you need a Configuration instance, though the examples I found don't work for me. They all set the instance to a Configuration field but that doesn't seem to exist. These Configuration lines are all red because the name doesn't exist:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup() {
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });

        app.UseMvc(m => {
            m.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
}
```

This is using the default Startup class from the empty project. I added the gulp and angular Node modules manually. I must be missing something but I have no idea what...

**Update:** These are my usings in Startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration;
```

**Update:** This is my current `project.json` file (I haven't modified this manually yet):

```
{
    "webroot": "public",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",

    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5"
    },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "public",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

**Update:** After changing the `beta5`s to `beta7`s, based on comments, I got past this `ConfigurationBuilder` error and moved on to a "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr' or one of its dependencies" error, which I suspect is another version issue and I'm looking into now...but that would be a different question I suppose.

Comment: What version are you using? Beta7?

Comment: Looks like OP is using beta3, there may be breaking API changes.

Comment: Sorry I should have posted the project.json. I'll do that now.

Comment: @Henk, based on that comment I changed my "beta5" lines to "beta7", saved, and this error went away. Now I have another error heh. I guess that's progress.

Comment: It would be nice if somewhere there were conflict/dependency checking to alert that a combination like this might cause issues...though managing that graph would probably be difficult.

Comment: If you want to edit your answer or make another one regarding the versions I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Josh you are now mixing beta5 and beta7. Make sure _everything_ is on the same beta. So make sure all the packages and the _runtime_ are on beta7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments by Henk Mollema, the reason `ConfigurationBuilder.Build` was not found and my `Configuration` lines were red is that I had mixed package versions (some beta5 and some beta7). This functionality was either added in a version later than beta5, or it couldn't be found due to the mismatched libraries. Upgrading to beta7 in `project.json` fixed it.

The subsequent error I mentioned was [fixed as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429163/vs2015-asp-net-5-beta7-dependency-could-not-be-resolved).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a few things here. Assuming you are on beta7 and you want a `config.json` file:

First build an `IConfiguration` instance in the `Startup` constructor:

```
private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
}
```

Don't forget to add the `Configuration` property to your class. Also, you need `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json` (`1.0.0-beta7`) for this.

Now in the `ConfigureServices` method you can bind settings from the. For example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Config.GetSection("AppSettings"));

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Do you know if the possible signatures for Startup() are documented anywhere? Almost every doc I find online uses a different one. This way of doing it is really frustrating so far.

Comment: @Josh the constructor can contain some runtime components which can be injected. `ConfigureServices()` can only have a `IServiceCollection` argument. `Configure()` should contain an `IApplicationBuilder` parameter and any other injectable type.