# VS2015 ASP.NET 5 beta7 dependency could not be resolved

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32396520). I started with an Empty ASP.NET project in VS2015 community, tried to add a couple packages based on a tutorial, and haven't gotten it to actually work yet. The initial problem in the linked question was due to some project dependencies using `beta5` and some using `beta7`. Matching those up solved that, but now I get this error when I try to run the project in IIS Express:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr' or one of its  dependencies.
```

I think the problem is still version related--like the previous `web.config` assembly reference issues--but I don't know how to deal with it yet. I tried modifying `global.json` based on a similar issue I found on GitHub, but now it doesn't build. It looks like it can't find the newer version of the CLR I guess. From the Error List in VS2015:

```
The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc >= 6.0.0-beta7 could not be resolved.
The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS >= 1.0.0-beta7 could not be resolved.
The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener >= 1.0.0-beta7 could not be resolved.
```

`global.json`:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "runtime": "clr",
    "architecture": "x86"
  }
}
```

My project's References tree has yellow error indicators but looking in the NuGet package manager for my project doesn't show any upgrades (or anything installed at all, as far as I can tell).

`dnvm list`:

```
     1.0.0-beta5       clr     x64
     1.0.0-beta5       clr     x86
     1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x64
     1.0.0-beta5       coreclr x86
*    1.0.0-beta7       clr     x86  default
     1.0.0-beta8-15585 clr     x86
```

`dnu list`:

```
Microsoft .NET Development Utility CLR-x86-1.0.0-beta7-15532
```

I've restart VS but that didn't help. Changing back to `beta5` in my `global.json` makes it compule successfully but then I get the IIS error.

`project.json`:

```
{
    "webroot": "public",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",

    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7"
    },

    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
        },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    },

    "publishExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.xproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],

    "exclude": [
        "public",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ]
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "ASP.NET",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "angular2": "2.0.0-alpha.36",
        "gulp": "3.9.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"To use ASP.NET 5 beta7 with Visual Studio 2015, you will need to download and install the beta7 version (14.0.60831.0) of ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015."

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623894

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/releases